# Отвязка от браузера.

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.
Может кто-нибудь посоветовать код для отвязки скрипта от браузера.
Т.е. выполнил запрос и забыл, чтобы висел в задачах, что-то вроде демона.
И главное, чтобы была возможность его остановить, тоже желательно средствами браузера...
Огромное спасибо.

UPD: 
Придумал небольшую заморочку, запускаю на вечное выполнение скрипт из браузера, а чтобы его закрыть чекаю файл допустим `stop.txt` и если он появляется то скрипт прекращает работу, а собственно файл этот создается еще одним скриптом например под именем `stop.php`.
Как думаете, возможна такая реализация?

Comment: Из того что позволит простой хостинг - cron + файл в ФС с командами

Comment: Ну я же написал через браузер, крон мне не нужен...
Думаю если поставить неограниченное время выполнения скрипта и завершать его созданием файла с опр. названием, именно с манипуляциями в файловой системе. Такой вариант реален или есть варианты проще?

Comment: Как вариант - сделать конвейер на javascript с использованием setTimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам мой велосипедик =)

```
<?
@ob_end_clean(); // чистим, если буфер включен
@ob_implicit_flush(1); // отключаем буфер
@ignore_user_abort(1); // не обрываем работу скрипта при обрыве соединения
@set_time_limit(0); // убираем лимит времени
if (!isset($_GET['key']) || ($_GET['key'] != '1234567890')) { // секретный код:)
  require 'textpage.php'; // страничка со ссылками
  exit;
  }
if (isset($_GET['stop'])) { // ссылка остановки: script.php?stop
  file_put_contents('break.txt', '1');
  header('Loaction: ?');
  exit;
  }
$i = 0;
$stoptime = time()+600; // 10 мин, поставите 0 - без ограничений.
// echo str_repeat(chr(0), 4096); // только для теста (в некоторых браузерах страница начинает показываться после "первых символов")
while(true) {
  echo ++$i.' ';
  @flush(); // на всякий случай, отсылаем буфер
  usleep(100000);
  if (($stoptime > 0) && (time() > $stoptime)) break;
  if (is_file('break.txt')) { unlink('break.txt'); break; }
  }

?>
```

Пример просто выводит числа столько времени, сколько вы ему скажете.

Хочу сразу заметить: нигде, кроме IE, оборвать соединение без завершения работы скрипта у меня не получилось, поэтому тут об этом не пишу. Варианта 2: либо сам скрипт запускать через `fsockopen` без ожидания контента(1 сигнальный символ отправлять, например), либо тупо самому в браузере нажимать "остановить"(не годится для "промышленного использования").

Comment: Ну и кстати, скоро, надеюсь, придут умные люди и расскажут, как запускать скрипты из консоли по SSH. Мои обстоятельства не позволяли этим заниматься + привычнее таки из браузера, нравится - пользуйтесь. Нет - ждите)

Comment: Спасибо, почти в точности такой-же код написал вчера, только функцию остановки вынес в отдельный файл...а по ssh я умею запускать скрипты и даже довольно часто пользовался пока не прознал всех чудес python =) только вот не пойму, зачем здесь буфер?

Comment: > Хочу сразу заметить: нигде, кроме IE, оборвать соединение без завершения работы скрипта у меня не получилось, поэтому тут об этом не пишу.

Единственный корректный способ тут - это использовать [php-fpm](http://php.net/install.fpm) и функцию `fastcgi_finish_request()`. После вызова этой функции php-fpm отправит ответ фронтенду как если бы скрипт уже завершился, но при этом продолжит выполнения самого скрипта.